# Entity Framework - Database mapping to get latest entry

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

Imagine a database with two tables: `Blog` and `Post`. Taken my scenario, the `Post`table has a property called `CreateDate`, which is equal to the date that the `Post` has been created. I have a relation between `Blog` and `Post`, where a `Blog`can contain many `Posts`, and I wish to have a C# model property called `LatestPost`. Here's an example:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual Post LatestPost { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to get the latest `Post`for this particular `Blog`, sorted by `Post.CreatedDate`. I can see that I can map things as I want to in the `Dbcontext.OnModelCreating()` if I were to override said method. I'm just not quite sure how to make this mapping. Is it possible for me to do this and get the latest `Post` for a `Blog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do so, your `Blog` should have *foreign key* to `Posts` like:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int LatestPostId? { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual Post LatestPost { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside `OnModelCreating` method you can map it like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasOptional(m => m.LatestPost)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.LatestPostId);
}
```

But I recommend loading `LatestPost` when you need it:

```
Post latestPost = myContext.Posts
    .Where(m => m.BlogId == blogId)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Additionally you can make `LatestPost` not mapped and configure it to load data from database:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }       

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual Post LatestPost
    {
        get
        {
            return Posts
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedDate)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to Ignore `LatestPost` in `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Ignore(m => m.LatestPost);
}
```

Additionally you can ignore this property by adding `NotMapped` attribute:

```
public class Blog
{
    ....

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Post LatestPost
    .....
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I though about just loading it whenever I needed it, but for some reason my head told that it was bad practice... Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Detilium, I am glad that it helped